# Help installing Visual Studio on Windows Server 2008 R2 via RDP

Tags: installation, rdp

I am connecting to Windows server 2008 R2 by RDC from Windows XP.Now I want to install Visual Studio 2010 at the server.
Can anyone tell me whats the way to do that??I am having ISO image of Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Deoends - seriously. How is the bandwidth between your two locations?

Answer (score 1):

My first choice given the likely size of the ISO would be to burn it to a DVD/USB and install it locally or via RDP from this locally-attached media. If that's not possible then I'd either mount the ISO or burn it to DVD on my own machine then use the shared local disk option in RDP to mount the code remotely on the server and install from there.

Also can I ask you to read our FAQ and perhaps have a look at some other questions before posting another question please, we want you here but your question title and tags didn't clarify your objectives.

Comment: I've done multiple VS installs on machines (often VMs) on the local LAN with remote desktop for the UI, and the installer across the network (often from the workstation I'm using for the remote desktop). Given sufficient LAN bandwidth this is not significantly slower than local install media. However if using a WAN connection I would want to get the installer local first (and I can see cases where a fresh download from MS might be quicker to the remote site depending on the relative WAN bandwidth).

Comment: Good points Richard.